# RunProcess : Save directly to Mathematica Variable

Tags: functions, function-construction, import, files-and-directories, external-calls

I can convert `mysource.jpg` to `myresult.jpg` using an external program `myprog.exe`, and set a variable to the resulting file. :

```
RunProcess[{"C:\\myfolder\\myprogram.exe", "mysource.jpg", 
  "/myoption", "myresult.jpg"} ]

MyVar = Import["myresult.jpg"]
```

Question ) But can I **save** data generated in an external program, **directly to a Mathematica Variable**, without creating a temporary file (like `myresult.jpg`)?

I tried the following code, and failed.

```
RunProcess[{"C:\\myfolder\\myprogram.exe",  "mysource.jpg", 
  "/myoption", MyVar} ]
```

If you think there is no general method, you can comment negatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be possible to do what you say, if `myprogram.exe` can output the image data directly to stdout.  But I wouldn't lose any sleep over having to create a temporary file, just make sure to clean up afterwards:

```
MyVar = WithCleanup[
    file = FileNameJoin @ {$TemporaryDirectory, "myresult.jpg"},
    RunProcess @ {"C:\\myfolder\\myprogram.exe", "mysource.jpg", "/myoption", "myresult.jpg"};
    Import @ "myresult.jpg",
    DeleteFile @ file
]
```

Comment: Probably `file = CreateFile[]` would be safer and more idiomatic.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - for sure, but I don't know if `myprogram.exe` uses the file extensions to determine output format. There is also the internal undocumented function  ```ImportExport`FileUtilities`TempFileName``` which takes a file extension as an argument.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to define `MyVar` without creating any temporary file on disk ? I mean directly from RAM to mathematica variable.

Comment: @imidak - I understood your question, and it depends on "if myprogram.exe can output the image data directly to stdout".  If it can, then you can use the output from `RunProcess` to get the image.  I was just giving my experience as someone who has written many functions using `RunProcess`, that writing to a temporary file is not usually a problem.

Comment: Thank you, in my case myprogram.exe could not output the image data directly to stdout.